# PySpark: How to Transpose multiple columns in a Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot, transpose

I am new to Spark and need a help with transposing the below input dataframe into the desired output `df` (Rows to Columns) using PySpark or Spark Sql.

Input Dataframe-

```
A    B    C   D

1    2    3   4

10   11   12  13
......
........
```

Required Output (transposed) data

```
A  1

B  2

C  3

D  4

A  11

B  12

C  13

D  14

....
......
```

It is better if I can pivot the input data (columns) as per our requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Use **`stack`** function in spark.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  A|  B|  C|  D|
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  1|  2|  3|  4|
#| 10| 11| 12| 13|
#+---+---+---+---+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.selectExpr("stack(4,'A',A,'B',B,'C',C,'D',D) as (key,value)").show()
#+---+-----+
#|key|value|
#+---+-----+
#|  A|    1|
#|  B|    2|
#|  C|    3|
#|  D|    4|
#|  A|   10|
#|  B|   11|
#|  C|   12|
#|  D|   13|
#+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a generalized function like below (inspired from my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62087822/9840637)):

```
def stack_multiple(data,cols=None,output_columns=["col","values"]):
    """stacks multiple columns in a dataframe, 
       takes all columns by default unless passed a list of values"""

    cols = data.columns if cols is None else cols
    cols= [cols] if isinstance(cols,str) else cols

    return data.selectExpr(f"""stack({len(cols)},{','.join(map(','.join,
               (zip([f'"{i}"' for i in cols],[f"`{i}`" for i in cols]))))}) 
                as ({','.join(output_columns)})""")
```

---

**Sample Runs:**

```
stack_multiple(df).show()

+---+------+
|col|values|
+---+------+
|  A|     1|
|  B|     2|
|  C|     3|
|  D|     4|
|  A|    10|
|  B|    11|
|  C|    12|
|  D|    13|
+---+------+

stack_multiple(df,['A','B'],output_columns=['A','B']).show()

+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  A|  1|
|  B|  2|
|  A| 10|
|  B| 11|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[10,11,12,13]]).toDF('A','B','C','D')
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|
| 10| 11| 12| 13|
+---+---+---+---+


df.select(
    F.explode(
        F.create_map(
            *reduce(lambda x, y: x+y,
                [[F.lit(col), col] for col in df.columns]
            )
        )
    )
)
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  A|    1|
|  B|    2|
|  C|    3|
|  D|    4|
|  A|   10|
|  B|   11|
|  C|   12|
|  D|   13|
+---+-----+
```