# How can I transpose a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

how can I go from a dataframe with the following structure:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |

to a result like this, **without using pandas** only pyspark.

| x | TRUE | FALSE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col1 | 5 | 0 |
| col2 | 2 | 3 |
| col3 | 3 | 2 |

NOTE THAT THE TRUE/FALSE COLUMN IS A COUNT OF THE NUMBER OF TRUE/FALSE THAT EXIST IN EACH COLUMN

Thanks!!

Comment: you can try `df.selectExpr(stack_multiple_col(df)).groupby("col").pivot("values").agg(F.count("values"))` after defining this function:  **[stack_multiple_col](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65047489/9840637)**

Comment: how about [pivoting](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot)?